# What are some good developer resources for QML/Qt Quick?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have seen the tutorial for the mobile platform on the [Ubuntu developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), but I am completely new to the Qt stack. Are there any other good resources for getting started with Qt/QML/Qt Quick?

Comment: If you go through the tutorial, there is a list of QML resources at the end. The tutorial itself does not assume previous knowledge of QML or Qt, so you should be good to follow it.

Comment: Take a look at http://qmlbook.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtquick.html - Specific to Qt 4.7, but has a wide variety of topics to do with QML, and Qt Quick
- http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Developing_with_Qt::Qt_Quick - Variety of demo's, tutorials and best practices
- http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-tutorial.html - Hello World tutorial, which leads onto an animation effect
- http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Quick_Tutorial - Currently only has 2 sections done - for the topics basics and components

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdeclarativeexamples.html

Answer (score 2):

I found these videos to be valuable starting point:

- [Programming with Qt Quick 1/6 - Meet Qt Quick Part 1](http://youtu.be/Zna1KHQj_8Y)
- [Programming with Qt Quick 2/6 - Meet Qt Quick Part 2](http://youtu.be/2nePnVQrPgo)
- [Programming with Qt Quick 3/6 - Visual Elements Part 1](http://youtu.be/lMSngoo4J7I)
- [Programming with Qt Quick 4/6 - Visual Elements Part 2](http://youtu.be/vz-WZZyfDO8)
- [Programming with Qt Quick 5/6 - States Animations](http://youtu.be/Pb2FX8G6Dno)
- [Programming with Qt Quick 6/6 - C++ Integration](http://youtu.be/n3JJZRQG39o)
- [QtQuick and Input Events (Touch, Mouse, Keyboard)](http://youtu.be/yTsCkfTAl1s)
- [Introduction to Qt Quick Controls](http://youtu.be/JLLIYysXsj8)
- [Python 3 and Qt 5 with QML](http://youtu.be/2HAFOZ5_Xks)
- [QmlWeb -- Running QtQuick Applications on the Web](http://youtu.be/Ea8Maw4FTw8)